# Disclaimer screen when adding new content

Tags: nodes, webforms, organic-groups

I'm looking for a way to have a disclaimer page/popup be a part of creating a certain type of content, in this case a OG group. Is this something that could somehow be done with Webforms?

I found http://drupal.org/project/legal but it just doesn't quite do the trick... Any other ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this would be to make a small custom module utilizing [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).  Substitute "example" with your module name to implement.

example.module

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_form_alter()
* Add Disclaimer Message to Article Create Form
*/
function example_form_article_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  if (arg(1) == 'add') {
    drupal_set_message('Legal Disclaimer: By filling out this form you are agreeing.','warning');
  }
}
```

example.info

```
name = "Example module"
description = "Adds a disclaimer to node/add/article page."
package = Example
core = 7.x
```

Or if you want a popup, you could instead use [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) and a little Javascript

example.module

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_form_alter()
* Add Popup Disclaimer to Article Create Form
*/
function example_form_article_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  if (arg(1) == 'add') {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'example').'example.js');
  }
}
```

example.js

```
// if user agrees continue, else redirect
if (!window.confirm('Legal Disclaimer: Press OK if you agree.')) {
  window.location.href='http://example.com';
}
```

Of course this is all pretty simple and ugly.  One could combine both approaches and using [CTools Modal](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/ctools_ajax_sample_page/7) or [JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) build a prettier dialog.  With JQueryUI you might do:

example.js

```
// if user agrees continue, else redirect using JQueryUI
// requires JQueryUI loaded (you can use [drupal_add_js()][5] for this too).
(function ($) { 
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $("<div><h3>Legal Disclaimer</h3><p>Do you agree?</p></div>").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "I Agree": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "No Way": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          window.location.href='http://example.com';
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```